# Text for honors college algebra and trigonometry

Tags: algebra-precalculus, reference-request, education

I am looking for suggestions on algebra and trigonometry for students who are interested in majoring in mathematics. So typical texts written for average freshman who is forced to take math as a core course is not suitable.

Comment: Trigonometry is a rather obscure subject as a major-or even at the undergraduate level. Still, one suggestion is "Advanced Trigonometry" by Durell and Robson, 1930. As far as Algebra is concerned, the subject is too broad to encompass in a single book, as is the case in undergrad studies where various courses of Linear Algebra, Absract Algebra are typically offered. So, you probably need to be a bit more specific I think.

Comment: Aren't these subjects taught in high school?

Comment: I concur with @MathematicsStudent1122 I would think that an honors student would already know this material.

Comment: Presumably OP is referring to freshmen in *high school*.  That is 9th graders.  Around here 9th grade is when the advanced students get to "Algebra 2".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look at [*Basic Mathematics*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387967877) by the ever productive Serge Lang. The title is definitely understatement compared to other "college algebra" and precalculus texts, but it's quite accurate from the perspective of a mathematician. As a bonus, it's considerably cheaper than standard College Algebra / Precalculus texts (including the ones my university uses for college algebra).

From the Foreward:

> Years ago, the colleges used to give courses in “college algebra” and other subjects which should have been covered in high school. More recently, such courses have been thought unnecessary, but some experiences I have had show that they are just as necessary as ever.
>
> [...]
>
> If only preparatory material for calculus is needed, many portions of this book can be omitted, and attention should be directed to the rules of arithmetic, linear equations (Chapter 2), quadratic equations (Chapter 4), coordinates (the first three sections of Chapter 8), trigonometry (Chapter 11), some analytic geometry (Chapter 12), a simple discussion of functions
> (Chapter 13), and induction (Chapter 16, §1). The other parts of the book can be omitted.

It seems to have, more or less, the standard stuff (condensed fairly significantly), plus some flourishes like isometries (in general, significantly more geometry than is standard) and permutations. I couldn't find the Table of Contents online or I would have included a link.

Answer (score 2):

*Precalculus, Mathematics for Calculus, 4th edition* by James Stewart, Lothar Redlin, and Saleem Watson. This edition is a little old so you might be interested in a newer one, but this is the book which I learned precalc from and it was challenging. At the end of some chapters it has "problem solving"sections which should give most precalc student a headache (I know it gave me one), at least if they are not already involved in math competitions or what not.